# Java Server socket stuck on accept call (Android Client, Java Server)

Tags: java, sockets

Below I have put a fragment of code to help understand my problem. I have a server code, works fine for the first time the client loads and sends a packet. After the first packet is received, the server is stuck on "accept".

I have wireshark configured for this port, and the server is getting those packets. I just wonder why accept wont return more than once. Its driving me nuts.

Server Code

```
 public class DAPool implements Runnable {
 private ServerSocket serverSocket;
 private ArrayList<DA> pool;
 private LinkedList<Socket> clientConnQ;
 public DAPool(int newPoolSize, int serverPort) {
  try {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort, 500, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return;
  }
  poolSize = newPoolSize;
  clientConnQ = new LinkedList<Socket>();
  pool = new ArrayList<DA>(poolSize);
                DA deviceThread;
  for (int threads = 0; threads < poolSize; threads++) {
     deviceThread = new DA();
     connPool.add(deviceThread);
     deviceThread.start();
  }
 }
 public void run() {
    while (true) {
       Socket incomingSocket;
       try {
           incomingSocket = serverSocket.accept();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       return;
     }
     insertNewConnToQ(incomingSocket);
  }
 }


 private class DA extends Thread {
  private Socket clientSocket;
  private ObjectInputStream inputObjectStream;
  public DA() { 
  }
  public void run() {
   while (true) {

    while (clientConnQ.isEmpty()) {
     synchronized (clientConnQ) {
      try {
       clientConnQ.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
       ignored.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }
    synchronized (clientConnQ) {
     clientSocket = (Socket) clientConnQ.removeFirst();
     try {
      inputObjectStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
     }
        // Do something useful here     
                                    }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Client Code

```
public class SendQueue extends Thread {
 LinkedList<Message> requestQ;
 Message sendRequest, requestMessage;

 Socket clientSocket;
 OutputStream outputStream;
 ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

 public SendQueue(Socket newClientSocket) {
  requestQ = new LinkedList<Message>();
  clientSocket = newClientSocket;
 }

 public void run() {
  while (true) {
   synchronized (requestQ) {
    while (requestQ.isEmpty()) {
     try {
      requestQ.wait();
     } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
      ignored.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
    sendRequest = requestQ.removeFirst();
   }
   try {
    outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);    
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(sendRequest);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    outputStream.flush();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

 public int sendRequest(Message message) {
  synchronized (requestQ) {
   requestQ.addLast(message);
   requestQ.notify();
  }
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code with `code` button on the panel.

Comment: first timer, just fixed it. looks better now I guess

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You say that accept() doesn't return, but it is exactly how it is supposed to work. It is waiting for the next connection. Have you tried to connect more than once? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Ok, I tried to create teh clientSocket again, and it seems to work.     <pre><code>    try {
    clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2"), 32123);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
   }</code></pre>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a timeout being set on the serverSocket.

`ServerSocket.accept()` is a blocking operation so it will block until either an error occurs, a timeout occurs, or a connection is accepted.

Try

```
SererSocket.setSOTimeout(10000)
```

You also don't seem to be closing your streams when your finished.

Comment: I don't see why a timeout is necessary in this case. That method only waits for new connections and does nothing else. It could wait indefinitely and it wouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: From the question "server is stuck on accept". My understanding was that the OP didn't understand why it was simply sitting there.

Comment: Yes, I have put a snippet of code. As of now the accept returns the first time the client tries to connect, but subsequently it just waits on the accept. As of now I am not interested in the timeout, since the server needs to continuously wait for connections.

Comment: I tried closing the streams. 12-20 18:19:58.910: WARN/System.err(706): java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
12-20 18:19:58.910: WARN/System.err(706):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.getOutputStream(PlainSocketImpl.java:306)
12-20 18:19:58.910: WARN/System.err(706):     at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:515)
12-20 18:19:58.920: WARN/System.err(706):     at

Comment: I had to time out my streams for inativity and close it after a timeout. I guess socket programming does not cleanup a connection on inactivity or for that matter when clients just die.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that it is sticking on the accept call? Did you get a stacktrace that shows it waiting on accept?

Assuming it is getting stuck elsewhere I'm wondering if it isn't because *clientConnQ* is being held in one of your *DA* instances. The synchronized block covers the *// Do something useful here* section.

I wonder if it might work if you changed the code to be

```
synchronized (clientConnQ) {
    clientSocket = (Socket) clientConnQ.removeFirst();
}
try {
    ...
```

Once you have your clientSocket from *clientConnQ* then no other instance can process that socket.

Comment: Yup, I tried it. But I still am stuck on accept call.    System.out.println("Waiting on Accept");
incomingSocket = serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println("Accept Returned");

Comment: Something to do with the socket I guess. If I close the socket and recreate the socket, it seems to work.

Comment: Accept returns nicely everytime, if I add this piece of code.      clientSocket.close();
clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2"), 32123);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I got a $ for everytime I asked a silly question :)

Here goes. A client socket connects and thats when a server receives a accept call. For some silly reason I was waiting on accept for receiving further data from the client. Infact, I should just wait for something on the "stream" and then process the stream. I should not wait on the accept for that connection.

Accept is to be called to "connect" to the socket, not to receive data continuously.

Thanks for your all your help. You forced me to think about thread synchronization, the design, sockets in general and finally arrive that the solution.

Fantastic responses people. Thanks.
Siddharth